# Approximation to transcendental function by polynomial

Tags: functions, approximation

**UPDATE:** It is well known that for any irrational number $\alpha$, given a $\epsilon > 0$, the inequation :$$|\alpha -\frac{p}{q}|< \frac{1}{q^{2+\epsilon}}$$, if  $\alpha$ is algebraic, the inequation has finite solutions, if the inequation has infinite solutions, $\alpha$ is transcendental. This is what called Roth's Theorem.

Given an irrational  function, and suppose it is approximated by polynomials, is there any theorem like the Roth's Theorem?

Comment: Explore the Stone-Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: I think Roth's Theorem only goes one way; if $\alpha$ is transcendental, the inequality may still have only finitely many solutions. And what do you mean by "irrational function"? And how do you propose to measure how close an approximation by a polynomial is?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I will update the post, thanks.

Comment: @Aruralreader, thank you very much for your comment, why not answer the question by the comment?

Comment: You have what you need, best of luck in your studies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose by "irrational function" you mean a function that is not a rational function.
But maybe what you are really interested in, analogous in some way to Roth's theorem, is the distinction between algebraic functions and transcendental functions.  And one way (not the only way) of approximating functions by polynomials is Taylor series.  So, consider this.  If $f(z)$ is an algebraic function that is not a polynomial, then its Taylor series must have finite radius of convergence.  In other words, an entire function that is algebraic must be a polynomial.  See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104772/algebraic-functions-are-polynomials) for a proof.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the link